# How select random non-consecutive dates for every grouped element?

Tags: r, random, dplyr

I am currently trying to select non-consecutive dates for every grouped column.

In other words, I have the below dataframe:

[image]

I would like to basically `group_by(Site)` and then keep only 3 random non-consecutive dates for every grouped Site. For example, if HP37P1B has dates corresponding to 12th March, 13th March, 14th March and 7th March - I need a dataframe (for example) that only has:

`HP37P1B 12th March`

`HP37P1B 14th March`

`HP37P1B 7th March`

So far I have tried a number of stackoverflow posts that use `diff()`, `ave()`, and the `lubridate` package, but I haven't had any success.

**EDIT**

Based on comments below, I am trying to make this question reproducible

`dput(uniqueSiteDate)`

```
structure(list(Site = c("HP37P1B", "HP37P2B", "HP37P4B", "HP4008U", 
"INME03R", "INME03U", "INOA03R", "IPTO04R", "IPTO04U", "IPTO06R", 
"IPTO06U", "OLCAP2B", "OLCAP3B", "OLCAP5B", "PANMP1B", "PANMP2B", 
"PANMP3B", "STIN02R", "STIN02U", "UPMAP1B", "UPMAP3B", "UPMAP4B", 
"UPMAP5B", "UPMAP6B", "VAR210R", "VAR310R", "VAR310U", "VAR410R", 
"VAR410U", "HP36P1B", "HP36P3B", "HP36P4B", "HP4008R", "INBS04R", 
"INBS04U", "SEL107R", "SEL107U", "SEL207R", "SEL207U", "OLV110R", 
"OLV110U", "OLV208R", "OLV208U", "THEN10U", "HP37P1B", "HP37P2B", 
"HP37P4B", "HP4008U", "INME03R", "INME03U", "INOA03R", "IPTO04R", 
"IPTO04U", "IPTO06R", "IPTO06U", "OLCAP2B", "OLCAP3B", "OLCAP5B", 
"PANMP1B", "PANMP2B", "PANMP3B", "STIN02R", "STIN02U", "UPMAP1B", 
"UPMAP3B", "UPMAP4B", "UPMAP5B", "UPMAP6B", "VAR210R", "VAR310R", 
"VAR310U", "VAR410R", "VAR410U", "OLV110R", "OLV110U", "OLV208R", 
"OLV208U", "THEN10U", "HP37P1B", "HP37P2B", "HP37P4B", "HP4008U", 
"INME03R", "INME03U", "INOA03R", "IPTO04R", "IPTO04U", "IPTO06R", 
"IPTO06U", "OLCAP2B", "OLCAP3B", "OLCAP5B", "PANMP1B", "PANMP2B", 
"PANMP3B", "STIN02R", "STIN02U", "UPMAP1B", "UPMAP3B", "UPMAP4B", 
"UPMAP5B", "UPMAP6B", "VAR210R", "VAR310R", "VAR310U", "VAR410R", 
"VAR410U", "OLV110R", "OLV110U", "OLV208R", "OLV208U", "THEN10U", 
"HP37P1B", "HP37P2B", "HP37P4B", "HP4008U", "INME03R", "INME03U", 
"INOA03R", "IPTO04R", "IPTO04U", "IPTO06R", "IPTO06U", "OLCAP2B", 
"OLCAP3B"), Date = structure(c(18333, 18333, 18333, 18333, 18335, 
18335, 18335, 18338, 18335, 18338, 18335, 18333, 18333, 18333, 
18334, 18334, 18334, 18331, 18331, 18331, 18330, 18330, 18330, 
18330, 18332, 18332, 18332, 18332, 18332, 18325, 18325, 18325, 
18325, 18327, 18327, 18327, 18327, 18327, 18328, 18340, 18340, 
18340, 18340, 18340, 18334, 18334, 18334, 18334, 18336, 18336, 
18336, 18339, 18336, 18340, 18336, 18335, 18334, 18334, 18335, 
18335, 18335, 18332, 18332, 18332, 18331, 18331, 18331, 18331, 
18333, 18333, 18333, 18333, 18333, 18341, 18341, 18341, 18341,
18341, 18335, 18335, 18335, 18335, 18383, 18383, 18383, 18384, 
18384, 18384, 18384, 18385, 18385, 18335, 18342, 18342, 18341, 
18383, 18383, 18345, 18349, 18349, 18349, 18349, 18340, 18339, 
18340, 18341, 18339, 18386, 18386, 18348, 18346, 18347, 18328, 
18328, 18328, 18328, 18390, 18389, 18391, 18392, 18392, 18392, 
18392, 18392, 18392), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, -125L
), groups = structure(list(Site = c("HP36P1B", "HP36P3B", "HP36P4B", 
"HP37P1B", "HP37P2B", "HP37P4B", "HP4008R", "HP4008U", "INBS04R", 
"INBS04U", "INME03R", "INME03U", "INOA03R", "IPTO04R", "IPTO04U", 
"IPTO06R", "IPTO06U", "OLCAP2B", "OLCAP3B", "OLCAP5B", "OLV110R", 
"OLV110U", "OLV208R", "OLV208U", "PANMP1B", "PANMP2B", "PANMP3B", 
"SEL107R", "SEL107U", "SEL207R", "SEL207U", "STIN02R", "STIN02U", 
"THEN10U", "UPMAP1B", "UPMAP3B", "UPMAP4B", "UPMAP5B", "UPMAP6B", 
"VAR210R", "VAR310R", "VAR310U", "VAR410R", "VAR410U"), .rows = structure(list(
    30L, 31L, 32L, c(1L, 45L, 79L, 113L), c(2L, 46L, 80L, 114L
    ), c(3L, 47L, 81L, 115L), 33L, c(4L, 48L, 82L, 116L), 34L, 
    35L, c(5L, 49L, 83L, 117L), c(6L, 50L, 84L, 118L), c(7L, 
    51L, 85L, 119L), c(8L, 52L, 86L, 120L), c(9L, 53L, 87L, 121L
    ), c(10L, 54L, 88L, 122L), c(11L, 55L, 89L, 123L), c(12L, 
    56L, 90L, 124L), c(13L, 57L, 91L, 125L), c(14L, 58L, 92L), 
    c(40L, 74L, 108L), c(41L, 75L, 109L), c(42L, 76L, 110L), 
    c(43L, 77L, 111L), c(15L, 59L, 93L), c(16L, 60L, 94L), c(17L, 
    61L, 95L), 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, c(18L, 62L, 96L), c(19L, 63L, 
    97L), c(44L, 78L, 112L), c(20L, 64L, 98L), c(21L, 65L, 99L
    ), c(22L, 66L, 100L), c(23L, 67L, 101L), c(24L, 68L, 102L
    ), c(25L, 69L, 103L), c(26L, 70L, 104L), c(27L, 71L, 105L
    ), c(28L, 72L, 106L), c(29L, 73L, 107L)), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = c(NA, -44L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To answer other questions, sometimes there are more than 3 dates per site, but sometimes there is just 1 date per site. But the idea is to choose n Number of non-consecutive dates given a Site. In other words, if a particular site has 4 dates, I need 3 non-consecutive ones. If a particular site has only 1 date, let's just leave that in.

Comment: 1. Could you make the example [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)? 2. Are there always at least 3 dates by `Site`? 3. Is the "non consecutive" part a hard requirement? Or are solutions that sample 3 dates at random (thus possibly consecutive) satisfactory? And if not, is it guaranteed that there are not only 3 dates, but 3 dates that make it possible to find a solution?

Comment: Even your picture is not matching with the stated example??  Date in first `site` is same for all three rows.

Comment: I added more information to help answer this question @Aurèle

Comment: @AnoushiravanR See edits above

Comment: In the data provided, the all dates for first group are same?

Comment: @AnilGoyal If you notice clearly, they are different groups - HP37P1B, HP37P2B

Comment: Ok.  But the example is not minimal.  Please post `dput` such that it can be toyed around.  With six groups, one row each group, how can one make a random sample of three per group??

Comment: @AnilGoyal I have added the dput now. Please see.

Comment: What if 3 non-conscutive dates cannot be produced from those 4 dates, what then? You say you _need_ 3, so that's an error, right?

Comment: In which case, I think we should basically just keep 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check whether it serves the purpose?  Actually, selecting maximum possible dates with the provide criteria is difficult (at least for me).  We can identify dates in consecutive and non-consecutive groups by the following strategy.  But consider two scenarios from a group of say 3 consecutive dates.  If the *random* sample contains 2 units, these can be consecutive or non-consecutive as well.  Suppose if we further select either odd (2) or even(1) rows then the sample would have been judgmental and not random in my opinion.  This is the strategy adopted -

- splitted the data in groups
- carried out operations in each group separately through `purrr::map_df` which finally row binds the data
- divided the data (now groups) in consecutive and non-consecutive dates (each consecutive date will be in its own group).  Select unique row from each group.
- finally select three (or less as per group outcome) from each of these rows.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  ungroup() %>% 
  group_split(Site) %>% 
  map_df(., ~ .x %>% ungroup() %>%
        arrange(Date) %>%
        mutate(n = 1) %>%
        complete(Date = seq.Date(first(Date), last(Date), by = 'days')) %>%
        group_by(n = cumsum(is.na(n))) %>%
        filter(!is.na(Site)) %>%
        sample_n(1) %>%
        ungroup() %>%
        sample_n(min(n(), 3))) %>%
  select(-n)

# A tibble: 86 x 2
   Date       Site   
   <date>     <chr>  
 1 2020-03-04 HP36P1B
 2 2020-03-04 HP36P3B
 3 2020-03-04 HP36P4B
 4 2020-03-07 HP37P1B
 5 2020-03-12 HP37P1B
 6 2020-03-07 HP37P2B
 7 2020-03-12 HP37P2B
 8 2020-03-07 HP37P4B
 9 2020-03-12 HP37P4B
10 2020-03-04 HP4008R
# ... with 76 more rows
```

*Note: Your dput was grouped so I had to add `ungroup()` in second line of the code, which you may remove*

Comment: Thanks a ton @AnilGoyal. But, for the example of HP37P1B - there can be 3 non-consecutive dates that should be selected, but only two have been selected. For example, we could select 7th March (which you did), 12th March (which you did), but one could also select 14th March. Similarly for some other sites.

Comment: Yes exactly, but then sample won't be random.  It'd the only possible sample then

Comment: No, I meant - I wanted to select atleast 3 random non-consecutive ones. In your code, we  have selected only 2.

Comment: In the case of HP37P1B, atleast 3 non-consecutive ones can be selected, while for the case of HP36P1B, only 1 date can be selected.

Comment: ? Does that make sense? - Basically if I were to ask you to select any possible number of non-consecutive dates (at random), given the sample size.

Comment: Yes, this makes sense.  But you please imagine a scenario or three consecutive dates say 1, 2, and 3.  now random sample will either detect 2 or 1&3 both (sample from either even or odd numbered groups).  Now you have an additional criteria that sample should maximum possible output i.e. 2 which seems mathematically not possible (considering the randomness)

Comment: then in this example you actually want odd rows only and not random sample

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231451/discussion-between-anilgoyal-and-vijay-ramesh).

Comment: Aah, I see what you mean. Would it possible for you to show me how I can select odd dates then to maximize the number of dates chosen?

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I can't really test this on your data since it contains only one row per site (and thus only one date).

```r
l <- dat %>% group_by( Site ) %>%
    group_map( function(x,y) {

        n.day.increments <- sum( diff(sort(x$Date)) == 1 )
        n.2day.increments <- sum( diff(sort(x$Date)) >= 2 )
        can.have.3.dates <- n.day.increments >= 5 || n.2day.increments >= 2 || (n.day.increments >= 2 && n.2day.increments >= 1 )
        can.have.2.dates <- n.day.increments >= 2 || n.2day.increments >= 1


        repeat{

            if( can.have.3.dates ) {
                d <- x %>% sample_n(3)

                if( all(abs(diff(d$Date)) > 1 ) )
                    break

            } else if( can.have.2.dates ) {

                if( can.have.2.dates ) {
                    d <- x %>% sample_n(2)

                    if( all(abs(diff(d$Date)) > 1 ) )
                        break

                }

            } else {
                d <- x %>% sample_n(1)
                break
            }

        }
        cbind( y, d )
    })

sampled.data <- bind_rows(l)
```

Comment: Getting an error right now. Could you see the edits to the question?

Comment: This should work even if there is only one date associated with a Site right?

Comment: no, absolutely not, your updated question said that also 2 nonconsecutive dates was ok, so that was my new minimum requirement

Comment: I have edited the question further - please see.

Comment: you need to be super clear about this. What should the code do when it cannot fulfill 3 nonconsecutive dates. select 3 consecituve if possible? go for 2 nonconsectuve instead? what if it cannot produce 2 nonconsecutive but can do 2 consecutive, should it do those 2, or just return 1?

Comment: If there are 3 dates and all 3 are non-consecutive, let's keep them - else just choose 2 non-consecutive ones. If there is only 1 date - let's just keep that. If there are 4 dates, I want 3 non-consecutive ones. Does that help? Sorry!

Comment: what if 4 dates cannot produce 3 non-consecutive dates? what a site contains only 2 dates that are consecutive - should I then select just one or do you still want these 2? We can't guess these things...

Comment: Fair enough - if there are 2 dates that are consecutive, we keep only one. If there 4 dates that are consecutive, then we keep just 2 non-consecutive ones.

Comment: check the strategy proposed.  First, the code checks for consecutive date groups using `complete` function thereafter samples.  I am adding an explanation.  This way however, you cannot have more than one date per group of consecutive dates even when possible.  However, I am also thinking of strategy to include more dates from these kinda groups.

Comment: It's updated to produce 3 if possible, or produce 2 if possible, otherwise just draw 1

Comment: made some edits, struggled with the checks for 3 days or 2days. @AnilGoyal was that a comment for me?

Comment: Updated it again, the algorithm to check for 3 non-consec dates should be revised to somethign more elegant, but I think it will work now